# Specifying the number of pages in indeed URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am doing some web scraping in Python to find certain Keywords in Job descriptions in indeed job postings.

However I can only scrape through 2 pages. If I increment the number of pages to 3 (variable nopa), the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' occurs.
If anyone might have an idea why that is the case, it would be very helpful.

Here is my Code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

keywordlist = []
keywords = ["PYTHON", "JAVA", "SQL", "NOSQL", "MONGODB", "CASSANDRA",
            "AWS", "AZURE", "SPARK", "AIRFLOW", "HIVE", "HADOOP", "REDSHIFT",
            "S3", "KAFKA", "TABLEAU", "EXCEL", "QLIK", "POWER BI",
            "DYNAMODB", "WAREHOUS", "ALTERYX", "LAKE", "ETL", "CI/CD", "BASH",
            "SHELL"]

occurences = []
tags = []
nopa = 2

for i in range(nopa):

    url = "https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%" + str(nopa*10) + "engineer&l&vjk=144c9cb8990a7fc2"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    outer_most_point=soup.find('div',attrs={'id': 'mosaic-provider-jobcards'})
    for job in outer_most_point.find('ul'):
        point = job.find("a")
        if point is not None:
            tags.append(point["href"])

for i in range(len(tags)):
    url_href='https://de.indeed.com' + tags[i]
    response = requests.get(url_href)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    for i in soup2.find('div',{'class':'jobsearch-jobDescriptionText'}):
        keywordsublist = []             
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in str(i).upper():
                keywordsublist.append(keyword) 
        keywordsublist = list(set(keywordsublist)) 
        keywordlist = keywordlist + keywordsublist

for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in keywordlist:
        occurences.insert(keywords.index(keyword),keywordlist.count(keyword))
    else: occurences.insert(keywords.index(keyword),0)

df = pd.DataFrame( list(zip(keywords, occurences)), columns =['Technology', 'num'])
df = df[df.num != 0]
df = df.sort_values('num')

plt.bar('Technology', 'num', data=df, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show us what `response` looks like for that 3rd page?

Comment: what is this - `"https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%" + str(nopa*10) + "engineer&l&vjk=144c9cb8990a7fc2"` ? U re find "Data engineer", whitespace in link - `%20` . So for first page - `https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data%20Engineer&start=0` , second - `https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data%20Engineer&start=10`, third - `https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data%20Engineer&start=20`, etc

Comment: The response Code was always 200 (Ok). With Sergeys solution it now works. I thought the 20 indicated the second page with 10 listings, a 30 would be 3rd page and so on. Thanks a lot for both of your answers.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what URL you created. You have to use `i*10` instead of `nopa*10`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either update the last substring of the url as it follows a pattern:

url = https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data%20Engineer&start=0 -> first page

url = https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data%20Engineer&start=10 -> second page

url = https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data%20Engineer&start=20 -> third page ... and so on

Or, during each page, you can fetch the link of the next page in the Href attribute which is located in the pagination-list class name.